# Allow only one single up or down vote per visitor - PHP

Tags: php, mobile, laravel, ip, tracking

I know there are already some of these questions but I'am still not sure what to do.

**The issue**
I would like to have visitors being able to up or down vote once. First I thought I'd use the IP address to keep track of them, but apparently mobile IP addresses are changing frequently (mine every page refresh).

Other people state that you should track them by user id, but I don't want them forcing to register.

So... is there any way to keep track of unique mobile users. With either sessions, cookies, IP addresses or maybe something else?

For me sessions seem the best way to do it. It allows the users to vote multiple times, but not that fast and if it won't slow down the website to much.

To give you people an example: http://votezine.com/list/penguins-are-awesome-for-many-reasons-what-do-you-like-most

Comment: if they dont have to register, there no way, with any precision, to do this

Comment: Not that fast? If you use sessions the user can open an new private/incognito tab, vote close the tab open another one and vote again. And writing a program that does this probably isn't very difficult. Everything that's stored on the client (session(id) & cookie) can be manipulated by the user

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use browser fingerprint on top of the methods you've mentioned.

https://panopticlick.eff.org/index.php?action=log&js=yes

http://valve.github.io/fingerprintjs/

Comment: interesting, good thing i use multiple browsers